# How to align the textbox inside inline table with the text

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple situation that I can't for some reason resolve. In ASP.NET I am trying to align the textbox inside the inline table with the text so that the text will point at the middle of the textbox, not at its foundation

Here is the markup

```
    <span style="margin-bottom:10px">This is the text</span>

    <table class="inlineTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom;padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the css

```
.inlineTable {
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

As it is seen in the attachment, the text points at the base. How can I move the textbox a bit down so that the text would point to the middle of the left side?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please show us the **rendered** HTML. CSS is not concerned with any `.aspx` source-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try vertical-align:middle on the table

```css
.inlineTable {
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0;  
    
}
table{
vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<span >This is the text</span>

    <table class="inlineTable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                <textarea ID="TextBox1">hi</textarea> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```